# Register Users to Microsoft Active Directory From Registration form

Tags: .net, integration, adfs

I am a salesforce developer. I just know the basics of Dotnet. Now I have the requirement from our client to register users to Microsoft Active Directory via registration page. 
I researched in web and found Azure AD members sigle sign-on but not able to find how to register a user to the Microsoft Active Directly.

Currently our client using Server Manager to add users to active directory manually. Now they want registration form that automatically registers the users to microsoft active directory.

I just need an overview of this requirement like how we can do it with dotnet integration.

Thanks!

Comment: Please give comments for downvote. So that I can improve my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it would be possible to use the Graph API here, this was you can do it through an application instead of going through and doing it manually - but it would be worth clarifying what you mean in your post.

Cheers,
G

Comment: No - Graph API is for Azure AD not on-premises AD.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add users to on-premises AD, you can do it via the .NET classes - refer [Everything in Active Directory via C#.NET 3.5 (Using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/90142/Everything-in-Active-Directory-via-C-NET-Using).